# How to make firefox main windows have no decorations using devilspie?

Tags: window-manager, metacity

First off, I can't run Compiz. It doesn't work with my old ati.

I'm trying to make all firefox main windows have no decorations.

Here's the rule:

```
( if 
( and 
( is ( application_name ) "Firefox" )
( contains ( window_name ) "- Mozilla Firefox" )
) 
( begin 
( println "match" )
( undecorate )
)
)
```

It will undecorate any open firefox window. As long as one firefox window is open, it will undecorate any new windows. If I close FF and reopen, it is *not* undecorated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

(This was tested on Xubuntu 12.04, Xfce 4.10, with `xfwm4` as the window manager.)

It is definitely possible to have existing `firefox` windows *and* newly opened ones automatically undecorated if you are using the latest version of `devilspie`, version 0.22. This is in the repositories and available to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

There is also a gui called `gdevilspie`, but the rules it produced seemed inaccurate and often didn't quite work, so it is easiest to concoct a rule by reading the readme and the manpage.

**How the rule was created**

All rules created must go in `~/.devilspie`, and have a `.ds` extension, so firstly create the folder if it doesn't exist with

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie
```

If you want to experiment to find the best window matching condition (class,name,etc), you can create a new file in `~/.devilspie` called `test.ds` and place in it `(debug)` . Now you can enter `devilspie &` and then for every program that you launch, `devilspie` will examine and provide some window information in the terminal:

```
Window Title: 'Mozilla Firefox'; Application Name: 'Firefox'; Class: 'Firefox'; Geometry: 1280x970+0+27
```

In this case, it is best to select Class (`window_class`), as that will reliably identify the window.

**The rule**

Create a new file called `firefox.ds` in `~/.devilspie` and place in it:

```
; firefox rule to undecorate all existing and new windows     

(if (is (window_class) "Firefox") (undecorate))
```

Comments are introduced with `;` and are not read. You do not need to use `begin` in the command unless you are specifying multiple actions, such as `(begin undecorate (set_workspace  2)))` instead of just the single action `(undecorate))`.

However, for `devilspie` to read the new rule you must restart it, so run

```
killall devilspie
```

and then restart it with

```
devilspie &
```

You have to do this **every time** when you edit a rule or add a new one in `~/.devilspie`, otherwise the changes or any new rules will not be read.

It is also very **important** that you add it to startup applications using your desktop environment's menus.

For more information on other possibilities with `devilspie`, see `man devilspie` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/devilspie.1.html).