# gnome-open window positioning

Tags: gnome, command-line, gnome-terminal

I've been using Ubuntu since 10.04, and seriously loving life. I'm on 12.04 and it's great.

As some super users would know:

```
gnome-open /home/username/somefile.txt
```

will open a window in gnome.

Is it possible to open a window and place it a corner of the window from the command line?

```
gnome-open /home/username/somefile.txt -top -left
```

(I know the command is made up)
This would be the equivalent of opening the file and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way of doing this with `gnome-open` itself, as it is impossible to pass geometry options to the program that will open your designated file.

The only feasible way to specify window geometry would be to set it beforehand in various profiles for your favourite programs by using `devilspie`, so that when you run

```
gnome-open ~/my.pdf
```

`devilspie` will load your profile for say `evince`, and set the window geometry as the window appears. If you are using compiz, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default) for how to specify window settings, as `devilspie` might not work with all window managers.

`Devilspie` can be installed from the repositories, and I discuss it in much more detail [in this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37111/how-to-make-firefox-main-windows-have-no-decorations-using-devilspie). In brief, the configuration file for the target program must be in `~/.devilspie` and end in `.ds`. Below is an example of one tailored for `gedit`, labelled `gedit.ds`:

```
; gedit geometry

(if (is (window_class) "Gedit") (geometry "662x742+0+27"))
```

You will need to specify your own desired geometry that is appropriate for your screen, and put `devilspie` in startup applications. You can run `killall devilspie` and then `devilspie &` so that any configuration changes to files in `~/devilspie` are re-read.